# What if the question has been answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion

If the correct answer has been posted as a comment, how could the question be resolve as no one will answer?

See [I have Nissan Altima 2013 model S, not sure what type of disks will play in the factory fitted disk player](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7868/i-have-nissan-altima-2013-model-s-not-sure-what-type-of-disks-will-play-in-the) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted a comment as a reply asking the commenter to post their comment as an answer. If they don't reply in a few days I wouldn't have a problem with someone posting that comment as an answer, improving on it of course, since it's only a link.

Comment: Exactly: the goal is actual answers.  Think of it as a freebie!